# Driving through Croatia: can someone tell me where I took this photo?

Tags: road-trips, identify-this, croatia, locate-this

While driving through Croatia I stopped on the highway to take a photo of a view I liked and I thought "I want to find it later in GMaps".

As I had the GPS off, and as I have a terrible memory when it comes to foreign names, I'm obviously not able to find the place anymore on a map :-D

Here it goes

[image]

Hints:

- I entered the highway (the E71) coming from Senj, heading south, and I think the photo should be no more than 200 km after that
- There were sign forbidding to take photos just a few hundreds meters after, for being there an airport.

Comment: And were you on the D8 section of the Adriatic Highway from Senj to Rijeka?

Comment: @Dorothy Does the D8 have any four-lane segments?

Comment: Was it before, or after, you went through a long tunnel?

Comment: @GayotFow: I drove a motorbike loaded with all stuff I own, for 2k chilometers in 3 days, part of them by night, on dark roads in the woods, on mountains, and at freezing temperatures. I'm glad I still remember my name ;-D. Tunnels? I have no idea :-D

Comment: @Dorothy: I was on D8 before entering the E71, if that's what you mean :-)

Comment: Anyone for a game of [geoguessr](https://geoguessr.com/) ... ? ;)

Comment: @pnuts: well...I'll post another one in a couple of day, so...prepare yourself ;-)

Comment: @pnuts I swear I tried. I think the problem here is my connection speed and I'm using Google Maps with IE. And anyway, I think if the question can be interesting, and funny, why not? ;-)

Comment: @pnuts I checked again: another of the reasons I wasn't able to find it it's that I didn't expect to have travelled so fast/so far. I left Rijeca at about 9 in the morning, and by driving on the coast it would take about three hours to reach that point. But I went really slow, and get lost a few time, so even if the photo was taken at 12.38, I thought I was much behind that area

Answer (score 45, accepted):

On the E65 interchange north of [Stupica](http://www.jasenice.hr/)...

[image]

Comment: Is that truck stucked there? Can someone call a mechanic for him?

Comment: @mgarciaisaia If it's stuck, they already managed to get a crew out there to do a paint job. I think they're okay.

Comment: It also shifted the lane

Comment: @mgarciaisaia It's a different truck.

Comment: But why does it always show up when you take a photo?..

Comment: Oh wow thats a hell of a coincidence.

Comment: @Malcolm you you suggesting the OP made a screen shot from Google? Interesting...

Comment: it's really amazing someone knew just where this is!

Comment: @JoeBlow not amazing, there's only 1 place where the E71 abuts a body of water and is 4 lanes.

Comment: I see, cool!  :)  I love the conspiracy theory that Moto actually *retouched a google image*  :)

Comment: Lol everybody :-D